# ajax select2 setup return error

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to setup ajax for select2. but im getting an error
TypeError: data is undefined[Learn More] select2.js:3543:23

```
$('#select-city').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select city',
    allowClear: true,
    theme: 'bootstrap',
    tags:true,
    delay: 250,
    ajax: {
        url: function (params) {
            return '/structure/ajax/ac_cities.php';
        },
        quietMillis: 200,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term
            };
        },
        results: function (data) {

                console.log(data);

        }
     }
});
```

my json return is : 
{"1":"Toronto","3":"Toronttto"}